# List of Java Connection (JDBC) non-db specific properties?

Tags: java, jdbc

Where can I find a good (maybe official) source (list) of non-db specific properties (keys)?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(key, value);
props.put(key, value);
props.put(key, value);
props.put(key, value);
props.put(key, value);
props.put(key, value);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path, props);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)) Javadoc:

> `info` - a list of arbitrary string tag/value pairs as connection
> arguments; normally at least a "user" and "password" property should
> be included

Other than that, neither the Java API documentation nor the [JDBC 4.3 Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/index.html) make any mention of properties that must be supported for `DriverManager.getConnection`.

Section 9.6.1 does specify a number of properties for `javax.sql.DataSource` objects, but of those, only `"roleName"`, `"user"` and `"password"` make sense for `DriverManager.getConnection`.

In short, the list of non-db specific properties is `"user"` and `"password"` (established by the Javadoc), and maybe `"roleName"` (though that requires inferring behaviour based on requirements for `javax.sql.DataSource`). Everything else is driver-specific and you will need to check the documentation of the driver you're using for the properties it supports.

In theory, you can discover properties through [`Driver.getPropertyInfo​(String url, Properties info)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getPropertyInfo(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)). However, its behaviour is - in my opinion - not specified clearly, so support and behaviour varies by driver (some return all properties, some only the minimum set of properties required to connect).